# BigQuery showing 0 results but Looker showing 2

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to get data for all campaigns that have a traffic_source.source of Linkedin and traffic_source.medium of paid for one day, and here's my code:

```
SELECT traffic_source.medium, traffic_source.name, traffic_source.source, COUNT(*)
FROM `nth-glider-369017.analytics_316822874.events_20230206`
WHERE event_name = 'sr_job_completed_application'
AND traffic_source.medium = 'paid'
GROUP BY traffic_source.medium, traffic_source.name, traffic_source.source
```

I get 0 results, however when i do the same thing in Looker Studio, I see that I have 2 events
[Paid LinkedIn event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2jUP.png)

Why would BQ be showing different data than Looker for that?

Comment: Please look for the uppercase of 'Paid' and not 'paid'. `traffic_source.medium = 'Paid'`

Comment: I did that, but still no data in BQ. Even changed it to Linkedin, but no data for Paid: Linkedin as source: https://imgur.com/a/SP8CBth
Paid as medium: https://imgur.com/a/i0kAzV7